# how to achieve google translate functionality in android builds

Tags: android, google-translate

i want to translate some word in to another language using google translate api for this i have added translate.jar file in code but its always giving null

```
public class Translator extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
String translatedText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        Translate t = new Translate() {

            @Override
            public String[] execute(String[] arg0, Language[] arg1, Language[] arg2)
                    throws GoogleAPIException {
                 Log.i("varun", "1");
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String[] execute(String arg0, Language arg1, Language[] arg2)
                    throws GoogleAPIException {
                Log.i("varun", "2");

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String[] execute(String[] arg0, Language arg1, Language arg2)
                    throws GoogleAPIException {
                Log.i("varun", "3");
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String execute(String arg0, Language arg1, Language arg2)
                    throws GoogleAPIException {
                Log.i("varun", "translatedText"+translatedText);

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return translatedText;
            }
        };

        try {
translatedText = t.execute("Bonjour le monde", Language.FRENCH, Language.ENGLISH);


//tv.setText(translatedText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}


        Toast.makeText(this, translatedText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        tv.setText(translatedText);

        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

its always giving null if someone have solution then please reply.
thanks in advance

Comment: seems like you do not understand your own code ... `String translatedText;` and then `return translatedText;` ... so what you expected? ...i'm assuming that you should get Translate interface/abstract class in different way but ILL NOT READ documentation for you ...

Comment: thanks for reply i am beginner in android i have override Translate and its override methods. when i override it then by default its returning null and here i am taking value in translatedText so i return it here. if you already solved this problem then please give me guideline.